# onDrag() fires multiple AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

So I am trying to create a drag and drop card game where user have to drag a stack of cards into respective categories. I want to congratulate user after they dragged all the cards into correct categories.

I have an activity extended `View.OnLongClickListener` and `View.OnDragListener` and also two layout, `topLayout` and `bottomLayout`. `topLayout` is where my pile of cards are, and `bottomLayout` is where the categories section are. I have six categories in `bottomLayout`, each of them is a `FrameLayout` and have their own `onDragListener()` set as shown in this code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    topLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.top_layout);

    findViewById(R.id.cat1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cat2).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cat3).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cat4).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cat5).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cat6).setOnDragListener(this); 

    generateCards(); // shuffle cards and put inside topLayout()

    ...
}
```

I also implement onDrag() method for the categories like this. Here is where my problem is.

```
...skipping onLongClickListener()...

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View receivingLayoutView, DragEvent dragEvent) {

    ImageView draggedImage = (ImageView) dragEvent.getLocalState();
    ViewGroup draggedParentLayout = (ViewGroup) draggedImage.getParent();
    FrameLayout bottomLayout = (FrameLayout) receivingLayoutView;

    // congratulate user when all cards dragged into correct place.          
    if(topLayout.getChildCount() == 0) {
        victoryDialog();
    }

    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            if (dragEvent.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {               
            return true;
        }
        return false;

...skipping other codes inside onDrag()... 

}
```

I have to check whether `topLayout` don't have anymore child views so I can congratulate user because they finished the cards. The problem is since I assigned listeners to six different layout of categories, my `victoryDialog` fires six times. How do I do so the dialog will pop up only once? Should I set a custom listener?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do to solve the problem (albeit in a hackish way I think) is just to implement [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for the dialog. Declare an `AlertDialog` variable above everything inside `Activity` class.

`AlertDialog singleDialog = null;`

Inside `victoryDialog()` method, rather than returning `AlertDialog` straight away I'll make sure to check whether an instance of `singleDialog` is already instantiated or not by checking the variable before returning `AlertDialog` in the form of `singleDialog`.

```
private AlertDialog victoryDialog() {
    if(singleDialog == null) {
        return singleDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Congratulations!")
                .setMessage("You made it!")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //nothing here
                    }
                }).show();
     }
}
```

This way, similar dialog will pop up once although the method fires multiple times due to `onDrag()` being assigned in multiple views since it can only be instantiated once by using this pattern.